# Personal Knowledge Base

Tags: knowledge-base

I'm already looking for a good Personal Knowledge Base software package for years now. I found this website and I thought I might give it another go.

I have a technical job which involves multiple disciplines. So I gather a lot of information and I don't want to lose this information as a lot of information is used once and maybe used months later of even longer again.

As an old fashioned engineer, I used to write down everything in a little book, dubbed my personal bible. Of course, over the years it became unworkable.

So I started using Alex PBK (http://pkb.sourceforge.net/) and was happy with it for some time, convinced the developer would make improvements. I mailed him several times with ideas, never got an answer and the software isn't updated since 2010!

So what I'm looking for;

- A knowledge base where I can easily make an entry with the click of a button
- where I can easily add images (jpg and such) and documents (like pdf's and docs) and when I click a document, it will open it in the appropriate software
- Must be searchable by keywords or tags

This may also be a website application I can run locally (MySQL?) or I can even use a hosting company so I can access my data whenever I need (I live in the Netherlands so 4G coverage is about 99% here)

I found a lot of solutions that come in the direction I'm looking for, but it's usually way way too complex. I asked around with fellow engineers and they were also enthousiastic about it.

Anyone knows of something like this? 
Or someone willing to collaborate to build the web driven application?

Please let me know!

Comment: What if it is *not* web-based? What OS/platform are you interested in? Win? Linux of some flavour? OSX? Have you looked at some of the Q&As tagged with [tag:note-taking]? Some of them might be relevant.

Comment: I'm interested in anything that runs on Windows. I'll check the Q&A's, thanks

Comment: It's just possible that [Treeline](http://treeline.bellz.org/index.html) would work for you in that case. I've written it up before on this site. If you think it's a contender, I'll add an entry as an answer here.... I don't know about attaching docs/files/pics, though, thus my hesitation.

Comment: This is mainly text based and although it's nice (I'll keep it for future use) it is not at all what I'm looking for.
I can't believe what I'm looking for does not exist, it is really simple and it alsmost makes me wonder if I should start programming it myself, unfortunately I don't have any programming experience at all so I wouldn't know where to start

Comment: I recommend you to use [tedegraph](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tedegraph.tedegraph) for reading information in subset of your knowledge base incrementally. This could be good complement to other tools you're using.

Answer (score 3):

> •A knowledge base where I can easily make an entry with the click of a
>   button
>   •where I can easily add images (jpg and such) and documents
>   (like pdf's and docs) and when I click a document, it will open it in
>   the appropriate software
>   •Must be searchable by keywords or tags

Sounds like you need a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)

Choose one to suit your needs [here](https://www.wikimatrix.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at that page.
I'm not sure which one to try yet

Comment: You can also see a list split by language etc, here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software. You can try https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki or https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki

Comment: Or use the wizard at https://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard

Comment: I do agree. I was in the same situation, searching an easy-to-manage personal knowledge base. And I've found a free wikifarm, with private wikis. And I'm really happy with it!

Comment: Would you care to share what you found?